# What's the best way to video chess/go/baduk/weiqi board from above (i.e. top down view)?

Tags: camera, grip

Are there special equipment to fix a camera in a top down view?

Answer (score 3):

*(This is an alternative to mounting a camera above a game board.)*

If it proves difficult to mount and operate a camera above the board, consider using a mirror as an alternative.  The camera can be placed on a normal tripod, and a mirror can be mounted above the board on a 45-degree angle.  The camera then shoots the image in the mirror.

[image: mirror over game board]

The image will need to be flipped vertically in post-production to avoid showing a mirror image of the board.

Comment: This has the advantage that the camera operator can adjust things without having to climb a ladder.

Comment: It's a good suggestion. It swaps the issue of placing the camera to placing the mirror. I don't know which is more difficult to do.

Comment: @xiaodai I'm not sure which is more difficult either! But mirrors usually have a wood frame which should be able to rest in a homemade stand more easily than a camera (depending on the design of the camera).  And as stib pointed out in his/her comment, the camera operator doesn't have to climb a ladder.

Comment: Just remember to flip the image horizontally with your editing software, or the board will appear reversed.